# how to add age with decimals (ex 20.2) to year and get it in yyyy format without decimals

Tags: r

I have two variable year of birth called yob in a yyyy-mm-dd format and age at diagnosis called agediag in a XX.X format. I calculated a variable that finds the age the person was 10 years before diagnosis, called agediag_10 also in XX.X format (by doing agediag-10). Now I want to find yeardiag_10, so I extracted year of birth (called yob) from the dob variable and it is in yyyy format. I added agediag_10 to yob and I have a variable called yearatdiag_10 which has decimals in it (yyyy.x format).

I'm trying to find the yearatdiag_10 without the decimals and have it in a yyyy format instead of yyyy.x (I can't just round because it won't be appropriate as i have to take in account the month of birth to be able to round which I can't do individually as I have a large database).

Here is the data :

```
structure(list(dob = structure(c(-309744000, -311385600, -382492800, 
-385948800, -386553600, -387417600, -387590400, -388800000, -389577600, 
-390700800, -707529600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    yob = c(1960, 1960, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 
    1957, 1947), agediag = c("50.2", "50.7", "51.2", "51.1", 
    "52.7", "50.5", "53.0", "50.2", "53.2", "52.8", "63.3"), 
    agediag_10 = c("40.2", "40.7", "41.2", "41.1", "42.7", "40.5", 
    "43.0", "40.2", "43.2", "42.8", "53.3"), yearatdiag_10 = c("2000.2", 
    "2000.7", "1998.2", "1998.1", "1999.7", "1997.5", "2000.0", 
    "1997.2", "2000.2", "1999.8", "2000.3")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

For example, for the second entry, the person was born February 2nd 1960. And at diagnosis he was 50.7 years (50 years 8 months), so 10 years before diagnosis correspond to year 2000 (so yearatdiag_10 = 2000 instead of 2000.7). And for the 3rd entry with the same calcul it should be 1999 instead of 1998.2. My reasoning is that the person was born November 18th 1957. He was diagnosed when he was 51.2 (so 51 years and 2 months, which means in january 2009). So ten years before diagnosis was in year 1999. So we need to consider the month of birth to be able to convert yearatdiag_10 from a yyyy.x format to an yyyy, but I'm not sure how to do it all at the same time (instead of one by one).

Thank you

Comment: Didn't you post this exact question yesterday? 

Comment: yes but it was not clear so I had to edit (text and title) and repost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to know that a date is just a number which you can add to subtract to.
First step is covert the dob to a just a date instead of a POSIXct object.  This way we are dealing with days and not seconds.  If we times agediag by 365.25 (days in a year) and add it dob we can generate the desired results.

```
df <- structure(list(dob = structure(c(-309744000, -311385600, -382492800, 
                                 -385948800, -386553600, -387417600, -387590400, -388800000, -389577600, 
                                 -390700800, -707529600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               yob = c(1960, 1960, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 
                       1957, 1947), agediag = c("50.2", "50.7", "51.2", "51.1", 
                                                "52.7", "50.5", "53.0", "50.2", "53.2", "52.8", "63.3"), 
               agediag_10 = c("40.2", "40.7", "41.2", "41.1", "42.7", "40.5", 
                              "43.0", "40.2", "43.2", "42.8", "53.3"), yearatdiag_10 = c("2000.2", 
                                                                                         "2000.7", "1998.2", "1998.1", "1999.7", "1997.5", "2000.0", 
                                                                                         "1997.2", "2000.2", "1999.8", "2000.3")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L))

#convert dob to a Date so we are dealing with days and not seconds
df$dob <- as.Date(df$dob)

#Convert age of diag to day
# substract 10 years of days
temp <- (df$dob) + 365.25*as.numeric(df$agediag) - 3652.5

df$yearatdiag_10 <- format(temp, "%Y")
```